# There a easy way to move/change a public folder structure exchange server 2007?

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2007, powershell

I looking to see if anyone has had any experience with restructuring a public folder tree that basically requires the movement of a public folder from one subfolder to another. I figure that we would need to use powershell for this, I am just looking for some guidance for this and any examples that would be of some help.

- Keep permissions and data of the moved/copy folder (which ever works)
- Keep the email address associated with the public folder
- Verification the permissions match, the data is intact and the email address is properly associated with the moved/copy public folder
- Removal of old public folder from the proper place (if needed)

I am hoping someone has had a similar experience with this.

Oh we are running exchange server 2007 8.01.0393.001 on windows server 2008 r2

Answer (score 2):

I have been trying to do the same thing myself recently, and I came across this link: http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2007/10/30/447339.aspx that helped to shed some light on migrating public folders.